# VirtualBox Terminal: Not Responding / Inactive

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualbox

I am having a problem using terminal in a Linux VirtualBox Terminal. This terminal is being used to compliment the StanfordOnline "Compilers" course on edX, the language for the class is called "cool".

Within this terminal I used the command "emacs 1.cl" in order to open the file "1.cl" with emacs. After I enter this command the file is successfully opened but the command prompt does not reappear, instead everything I type is just greyed text (see screenshot - Terminal is black window on left).

Why is this happening? I can start typing commands again if I close and then re-open terminal, but I think there must be a reason why this happens. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance, let me know if I can provide any more helpful information regarding the course or the software. Running VirtualBox on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 if it makes any difference.

-DR

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oweBG.jpg)

Comment: You ran emacs in the foreground. Which means control will not return to the terminal until emacs exits To run in background do: `emacs 1.cl&`

Comment: I see, thank you for the response!